# mobXterm and Win 10 - will the graphical SFTP browser work?

Tags: home-networking

Will the mobaXterm graphical SFTP browser work with a windows remote server? It works fine with a Raspberry Pi server, but not when I connect to a Win 10 PC. Am I missing a setting somewhere? Or does it only work with a Linux remote server?

Comment: mobaXterm works fine for me and I'm using win10.

Answer (score 0):

The SFTP browser operates only when you have connected to the remote server with SSH. No SSH -> no SFTP.

Windows doesn't come with an SSH server as standard so in that situation you won't be able to use the SFTP browser.